# Changing the order of axes in Mayavi

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I am generating STL files for 3D printing and then using mlab/mayavi to display them. I would like the `Z` axis to remain vertical as I rotate the image. According to the [mayavi documentation](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#changing-the-interaction-with-a-scene), this can be achieved using the following incantation:

```
fig = mlab.gcf()
from tvtk.api import tvtk
fig.scene.interactor.interactor_style = tvtk.InteractorStyleTerrain()
```

Unfortunately, as you can see from this screenshot of my app, it is not the Z axis but the Y axis that gets maintained vertical.

[image]

This is an issue because 3D printers always think of Z as the vertical axis, so I really need Z and not Y to be oriented vertically. Is there a way in which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problem, vertically aligned along the y-axis.

To get the scene to align vertically along the z-axis (which you want), you can simply add a `scene.mlab.view()` call before setting the interactor.

The `scene.mlab.view()` call aligns the camera correctly (with z up), before the interactor is set. I have found this solution by simply testing a bunch of stuff, I could not find this "hack" in the documentation.

New code:

```
fig = mlab.gcf()
from tvtk.api import tvtk
fig.scene.mlab.view(0, 90)
fig.scene.interactor.interactor_style = tvtk.InteractorStyleTerrain()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename them using the Mayavi button to access the pipeline, then selecting the appropiate axes object and changing the labels.

With code, you can add the `xlabel`, `ylabel` and `zlabel` keyword arguments to specify them. This is specified in the [`axes`](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_other_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.axes) API